# How to get ssl certificates using IP address instead of DNS (.net C#)

Tags: c#, ssl, dns, ip

I'm trying to get the SSL certificates using an ip address or if could be possible both (DNS and IP address), to be honest I don't have any idea about SSL certificates, I've been reading a little bit on it, I have to do it because is a new requirement and we have to use ip address that are not associated with a DNS (in some cases)

After search I found this solution:

```
//Do webrequest to get info on secure site
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txbURL.Text);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
response.Close();

//retrieve the ssl cert and assign it to an X509Certificate object
X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

//convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

//display the cert dialog box
rtbResult.Text = string.Format("Not Before: {0}\nNot After: {1}", cert2.NotBefore, cert2.NotAfter);
```

they asked only for the NotBefore and NotAfter date and is working if you use something like http://www.google.com but not with an ip address, do you know how could I use an ip address on it?

Comment: I believe most CAs will refuse to issue certificates that contain an IP address in either subject alternative name or the CN attribute of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently successfully pulled a certificate issued on a private IP from a local server (signed by an experimental CA, but this doesn't matter), so this is neither a bug, nor your app fault (probably - I used `HttpClient` class methods, but your code looks fine too).

The **real** question is, if the server you are trying to pull a certificate from, supports SSL/TLS on IP connections **and** has a valid (in the OS context) certificate assigned to its IP. On most modern webservers certificates are implemented on virtual hosts using [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and querying it only by its IP can return either a self-signed, untrusted certificate, an invalid (expired) one or no certificate at all, leading to SSL negotiation errors.

Comment: What I found is that use different ports that depends on the protocol... I had test some of them on unix that uses 990 (ftps), but if I do it with HttpWebRequest class from my C# program, I'm not able to get that values... how could I accept any protocol?